# Do "multiples" of open dense sets of an algebraic group union to the whole group?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group. From algebraic geometry we know there exists an open dense subset $U$ of $G$ such that $U$ is nonsingular. Since left multiplication of $U$ by elements of $G$ is an isomorphism of varieties, each $gU$ is open dense, and nonsingular.

How would you prove the claim that $ \displaystyle \bigcup_{g \in G} gU = G$? (From this, it would immediately follow that $G$ is smooth.)

Comment: $\bigcup gU = G$, not $U$. Pick $u \in U$ (it's certainly nonempty!). Now say you want to prove $h$ is in the union. Fine, let $g = hu^{-1}$. Then $hu^{-1} \cdot u = h \in gU$ and we're done.

Comment: Whoops, I meant the union equals G.

Comment: @DylanWilson: +1 and also, your comment is really the answer. I'd +1 that as an answer. Why don't you make it an answer. =D